# Redundant superclass constraint in swift 4

Tags: swift

I'm getting a `Redundant superclass constraint...` warning in swift4:
(paste in a playground)

```
import CoreData

class Item : NSManagedObject {}

protocol DataSourceProtocol {
    associatedtype DataSourceItem : NSManagedObject
}

protocol DataSourceProtocolProvider : class { }

extension DataSourceProtocolProvider {
    func createDataSource<T: DataSourceProtocol>(dataSource: T) 
         where T.DataSourceItem == Item {
    }
}
```

On the `createDataSource<T: DataSourceProtocol>` declaration I get the following warning:

`Redundant superclass constraint 'T.DataSourceItem' : 'NSManagedObject'`

I thought that you could specify that an associatedtype could be used with the `==` operator to constrain the associatedtype to a specific type.  I want to have a func `createDataSource<T: DataSourceProtocol>(dataSource:T)` where the `DataSourceItem` is an `Item`.

If I replace the `==` operator with `:` then the warning goes away:

```
extension DataSourceProtocolProvider {
    func createDataSource<T: DataSourceProtocol>(dataSource: T) 
         where T.DataSourceItem : Item {
    }
}
```

This happens to be a completely different context now.  This constraint specifies that I want to have a `func createDataSource<T: DataSourceProtocol>(dataSource:T)` where the `DataSourceItem` is a *subclass* of `Item`.  Which isn't the same thing as `DataSourceItem` *is* an `Item` object.
Also, the code runs fine with `==` so am I just not understanding how constraints work?

Comment: Constraints Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Comment: Top Google hit for "Swift redundant superclass constraint" is https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5862: It is a bug  which has been fixed only recently.